# Bootstrap navbar submenu Active State not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap navbar Active State is not working.

I have bootstrap v3.

I use the class="active" on mynavbar on its submenu when I collapse none work.

Here is my code with js/css/bootstrap files I have included:

```
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoadmin">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>Administrator Menu <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul id="demoadmin" class="collapse in">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="linkmanagement.php#">Links Editor</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="editortable.php">News Editor</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="main_category.php">Main Category Editor</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="sub_category.php">Sub Category Editor</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="editorprofile.php">Profile Team Editor</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Comment: can you add more code? Are you loading the right css/js's? Are you pointing to linkmanagement.php# ?

Comment: @alexandresaiz thats right, its my code https://ideone.com/7zIR1a

if main menu the class active can enable, but in submenu cant

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us enough HTML to see exactly what you are doing wrong, but it looks like you're trying to get the `active` class to work on a bootstrap `dropdown-menu`.

```
   <li class="dropdown active">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>Administrator Menu <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="linkmanagement.php#">Links Editor</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="editortable.php">News Editor</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="main_category.php">Main Category Editor</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sub_category.php">Sub Category Editor</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="editorprofile.php">Profile Team Editor</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/x15AyIXHz8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(".dropdown-menu li").addClass("active");
});
```